# XSLT to modify XML using XSD attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I want to modify my XML code using attributes of XSD.

### XSD :

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="uri" xmlns:vc="uri_1" xmlns="uri_2" targetNamespace="uri_3" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
<xsd:include schemaLocation="PolicyAdminGroupBenefits.xsd" /> 

<xsd:element name="FrequencyCode" type="xsd:string" /> 
<xsd:element name="BankAccountNumber" type="xsd:string" /> 
<xsd:element name="AmericanBankersAssociationRoutingNumber" type="xsd:string" /> 
<xsd:element name="BankAccount" type="BankAccount_Type" /> 
<xsd:element name="ElectronicFundsTransferPaymentTransaction" type="ElectronicFundsTransferPaymentTransaction_Type" />

<xsd:complexType name="ElectronicFundsTransferPaymentTransaction_Type">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element ref="FrequencyCode" minOccurs="0" /> 
<xsd:element ref="BankAccount" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" /> 
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="BankAccount_Type">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element ref="AmericanBankersAssociationRoutingNumber" minOccurs="0" /> 
<xsd:element ref="BankAccountNumber" minOccurs="0" />  
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

### XML code:

```
   <EmployerViewRootElement xmlns="uri_2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="uri_2 EmployerView.xsd">
   <ElectronicFundsTransferPaymentTransaction>
   <FrequencyCode>String</FrequencyCode> 
   <BankAccount>
   <AmericanBankersAssociationRoutingNumber>String</AmericanBankersAssociationRoutingNumber> 
   <BankAccountNumber>String</BankAccountNumber>  
   </BankAccount>
   </ElectronicFundsTransferPaymentTransaction>
   </EmployerViewRootElement>
```

I want to write XSLT code that will use `maxOccurs` attribute from XSD to check mandatory nodes (i.e. if `maxOccurs="1"` then element is mandatory) & throw error if those elements are not there in the source xml. Is it possible to write such a code?
Would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Validating an xml by xsd is the task of schema validator, why re-invent the wheel using xslt?

Comment: I am receiving source xml and I have to modify it according to my requirement, which is why, I am using XSLT to transform it. For checking mandatory elements I have to use maxOccur attribute from XSD because that is the only way to check it. But I am not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Solving the general problem is a very big project, and the fact that you are asking the question (and therefore don't understand the scale of the challenge) means you should not attempt it. It might be tractable if you reduce it to some very simple cases, where you know a lot about your schema in advance and can make lots of assumptions and impose lots of restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In this case, I will try some other approach to get the desired output.